# Please critique my high-current voltage regulator

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, mosfet, 555, ldo

A project I'm working on requires a source of power which need to be both regulated (5.00V) and high current (~4A). An external power source may be any from 6V to 12V but it can be assumed that it can handle required current.

I found out that there are very few high-voltage LDOs and they are very expensive. And none of precision and high-current LDO. I was looking at switching power supplies but they looks too complicated for me (I'm just hobbyist) and I don't understand how they work.

I developed following schematic (don't consider particular values of components, it is just a sketch). It consists of voltage-controller PWM generator which controls high-current driver on MOSFET. The output of driver goes to OP-AMP which evaluated difference between reference LDO and output of the driver.

So my questions are:

1. will it work in hardware as expected (it works on simulation)?
2. how stable/reliable this design?
3. maybe there are better solutions for a problem (like cheap ICs or modules)?
4. how do engineers usually solve such tasks (i.e. voltage stabilization/regulation under a high-current)?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH7nym.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: How are you expecting to pull 4A through those 10k resistors R2 & R3?

Comment: The datasheets for most linear regulators will show a way to use an external transistor to drop excess voltage.  This is inefficient, but easy.

Comment: We *need* to consider the component values. You have 20 kΩ between your 12 V supply and the output. Maximum current into a short-circuit would be 0.6 mA. You should also describe how you think this circuit will work.

Comment: With those components you are most of the way to doing a basic switch-mode (buck) regulator. That would be a far more efficient design than the shunt regulator you are trying to make.

Comment: We discourage broad, open-ended design review questions here on EE.SE: The answer(s) tend to become long strings of unrelated edits and/or comments. While this might help you with your immediate problems, it is of no value to the site overall. We DO allow design review questions in which you explain your choices and then focus on a few points about which you still have doubts. To get a better feel of what is or is not acceptable, search for "design review" on the meta site.

Comment: The reason you don't often see precision high current ldo is due to IR droop across pcb tracks or cables. You will need remote load sensing. Lookup lm723 for inspiration, this design won't work.

Comment: I see, the part with R2 and R3 probably incorrect. I guess, I should put higher R3 to have less current (R3-C1 only for voltage sensing) and the load should go instead R2.

Comment: What's the point of this Rube Goldberg system? What is supplying the rails of your opamp? Is it the same unregulated input? Is this whole thing an attempt to control a 5 V output from as little as 1 V headroom? Is that all this is? Just a linear supply for 5 V at up to 4 A?

Comment: @J.Doe You might examine [Semi-LDO Discrete +5 V Regulator](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yRFPJ.png). Something like that might do the job for you. Bear in mind that there could be a LOT of power dissipated in the D44H11 BJT. So you will need to be very aware of heatsinking that BJT.

Comment: @jonk That's a nice discrete regulator, however I do not think it will meet the 6 V in, 5 V out (so 1 V drop) requirement of this question. It might be doable with a PNP in a common emitter configuration as the main regulator. But that would need a complete design overhaul as it might introduce stability issues.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie It's a "semi-LDO approach. Not a true PNP-only. But it ***will*** work just fine with 6 V. That's because the overhead required is only one VBE plus one VCESAT. This is sufficient to scrape by. That said, I agree it is NOT a well-vetted design as provided there. Instead, that schematic was intended to show a possible path. I wanted to show a behavioral example that ***can*** be designed to operate correctly for this use. Keep in mind, it only requires VBE+VCESAT to operate. It can be brought into management on less than 1 V of headroom. I could NOT believe the crazy OP proposal!

Comment: @J.Doe [Fixed version](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ14q.png). The bode plot looks pretty decent, anyway. (Used Middlebrook's approach for that.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A circuit does rely on component values so you really should have made those realistic. Your circuit cannot deliver 4 A at the output as R2 and R3 have far too high values. It would need more than 80 kV (80000 Volts) to make 4A flow through 10 k resistors. So I'm assuming R2 and R3 have a value of a few ohms which should be more realistic.

*(1) will it work in hardware as expected (it works on simulation)?*

Theoretically yes **but** it will be extremely inefficient as you're just "burning off" any excess current through M1 and the resistors. At 4 A this will get very hot especially when there is no load. Which is just silly and not needed as there are far better solutions available.

This circuit is like driving a car at full throttle all the time and controlling the speed with the brakes. How long will those brakes last? What will be the fuel consumption? Bad!

*(2) how stable/reliable this design?*

I do not dare to say as it is too unconventional. As it is an inefficient solution, components get hot, hot components means a lower reliability.

*(3) maybe there are better solutions for a problem (like cheap ICs or modules)?*

Yes, there should be Switching DCDC (Buck) converters which can fit your requirements.

*(4) how do engineers usually solve such tasks (i.e. voltage stabilization/regulation under a high-current)?*

By using a **Buck converter**. I advise not try to build your own as the component layout (on the PCB) and the component choice is somewhat critical. I advise to get a module. Here's one [based on the XL4005](https://www.ebay.com/itm/5A-DC-DC-adjustable-step-down-module-XL4005-NEW-GOOD-QUALITY-M2-/351493105842?_ul=PA) which should fit your needs. The XL4005 can work with only 0.6 V voltage difference. It is cheap and easy to use. Don't forget to adjust the output voltage to 5 V before connecting anything to the output. The small screw on the blue trimmer sets the voltage.

In general it is a waste of time to "design" something like this in a simulator as I (having 30 years of experience with circuit simulators) can make "almost anything" happen in a simulator. I mean make circuits that will **never** work in the real world.

A simulator is a tool which need to be used to **confirm** what a circuit designer designs. Without sufficient knowledge of circuits a simulator's result / behavior can send you into a completely wrong / unrealistic direction.